# Storing and Retrieving Multi-Valued properties in Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, arraylist, google-cloud-datastore

Can anyone tell me how can i store Multiple values for an property in Google App Engine DataStore. I'am trying to do this in Java.

I have an property named tag and i want this property to contain multiple values. I heard that DataStore allows multi-valued properties but m not finding a way to do it. I tried searching the net for the same but couldn't succeed.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean list of tags or each `tag` has more than one property like `name` and `count`?

Comment: Ya its a list of `tag`. Tag is a property and i want that property to have multiple values for individual entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Entity post = new Entity("Post");
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
tags.add("foo");
tags.add("bar");
post.setProperty("tags", tags);
datastore.put(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Lipis's answer, here is how you would retrieve the multi-value property from the entity.

Assuming you put a List of values in the entity's property as described in Lipis's answer, the method getProperty("tags") will return a List with the values, as follows:

List tags =myEntity.getProperty("tags");

Comment: Please add an answer to the question in actual code. The link may go dead some time, and people should not need to follow it anyway.